# CSS Hover effect doesn't work when implemented

Tags: css, background, hover

i have troubleshooting with hover effects.

I'm working on a welcome webpage.

First i made an item list with HOVER effects :

```css
body {
background-color: #E0105F;
}

.welcome-menu-box{
position: absolute;
right: 10%;
bottom: 10%;
}

.welcome-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0D1033;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 1s box-shadow;
}


.welcome-menu:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.welcome-menu:hover::before, .welcome-menu:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #10E091;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: 1s clockwise infinite;
}

.welcome-menu:hover:after {
  background: #EADCB5;
  animation: 2s counterclockwise infinite;
}

@keyframes clockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;    
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;    
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;    
  }
}

@keyframes counterclockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;    
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;    
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    right: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;    
  }
}
```

```html
<container class="welcome-menu-box">  
  
<div class="welcome-menu">ABC</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCD ABCDEF</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCDEFGHIJ</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCDEFGHI</div>
  
</container>
```

And I tried to implement it in a specific DIV on a webpage :

```css
/* Div responsive encadrée pleine page  avec arrière plan couleur + image png centrée et répétée depuis le centre */


.welcome-menu-box{
position: absolute;
right: 10%;
bottom: 10%;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.welcome-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0D1033;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 1s box-shadow;
}


.welcome-menu:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.welcome-menu:hover::before, .welcome-menu:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #10E091;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: 1s clockwise infinite;
}

.welcome-menu:hover:after {
  background: #EADCB5;
  animation: 2s counterclockwise infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes clockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;    
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;    
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;    
  }
}

@keyframes counterclockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;    
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;    
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    right: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;    
  }
}

.encadrement {
  background: url('https://www.agence-mibe.com/CODEPEN/GROSMYO-fullresponsive.png') repeat center center fixed, #E0105F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 75px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: auto 70%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .encadrement {
  border: 50px solid #fff;
}
  
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .encadrement {
  border: 25px solid #fff;
  background-size: 70% auto;
  }
```

```html
<section class="encadrement">
  
  <container class="welcome-menu-box">  
  
<div class="welcome-menu">ABC</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCD ABCDEFG</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCDEFGHIJ</div>
<div class="welcome-menu">ABCDEFG</div>
  
</container>
  
  
</section>
```

I have two problems that I'm not able to solve :

• The second item which contains two world has a vertical misalignment due to the occupied space
• The hover effect doesn't work on the web page, but works when alone

If somebody could give me a hint it would be wonderful :-)

Comment: you omitted `content: '';` which is important, why you did it?

Comment: Oh, right.Thank you very much, don't know why I didn't see it